# Page need to refresh to get Datetimepicker everytime in Ember.js

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I am working on **Ember.js** and I am new to this. My question is related to `Datetimepicker`.
`Datetimepicker` is working fine for the first time, but to use it again I have to refresh the whole page.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="well">
<div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-append date">
<input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" type="text"></input>
<span class="add-on">
<i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
</i>
</span>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  language: 'pt-BR'
});
});
</script>
```

Please help me in this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The correct place for jquery logic is inside an `Ember.View`.

So, we'll assume that this HTML is inside a template. This template can have an optional `View`:

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
  setup: function() {
    this.$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
  }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```

Make sense?

Comment: There are a lot of things that can be going wrong. Ember has many moving parts. Can you provide a jsbin, or a github link? Or show more of your code?

Comment: You need an ember application, then routing, then you can hook up your view. As it is, with the code you have shown me, I can't tell where it is going wrong. Put your code in a jsbin and I'll try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's more of my code

HTML

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="user">
<div class="container-fluid"  style="text-align: center">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-mid-6">
            <form action="#" method="post" class="form">
            <div class=" main">
                <h3 class="text-center">Shutdown!!!</h3>
                <div class="well">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{view...... }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-append date">
                           <input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" type="text" placeholder="Start Date & Time"></input>
                              <span class="add-on">
                                <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar" class="icon-calendar"> 
                                 </i>
                               </span>
                          </div>
                    </div>

            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            language: 'pt-BR'
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm using following libs

bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js

bootstrap.min.js

moment.min.js